# Search for special characters in title only

Tags: bug

Sometimes people use `>` or `:` to post tags in titles and separate them afterwards, like:

> Excel 2003: How do I enter a formula

I tried to find those questions where `>` or `:` were used in this way to fix the titles and move their *tags* from titles to tags section.

I quickly checked how to use the SU search effectively under [Help center > How do I search](https://superuser.com/help/searching)

> To limit your search to just the title of a question, use **title:** followed by the search term
>
> To find a specific phrase, or to search a string of special characters, **enter it in quotes:** like "flat tire", or "<%#".

But when I use the SU search bar and enter `title:">"` or `title:":"` I got no results. Of course there certainly [are](https://superuser.com/questions/736683/zsh-tab-completion-to-run-scripts-in-current-folder-tabscrtab-script-s/736902#736902) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/364029/copy-title-attribute-from-a-title-to-clipboard-in-chrome) containing them in their title.

Apparently the `title:`  parameter together with special characters enclosed in quotes don't work. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm you're right, this isn't currently supported (not in a title-only way). If it's something that's asked for me we can see how to approach it. It would not be trivial to add, though.